# Ejecutar macros de IMS desde Excel

Tags: excel, vbs

en mi trabajo utilizo el programa IMS de IBM, en el tengo varias macros grabadas para facilitar muchas tareas rutinarias. Me gustaría ejecutar estar macros desde Excel, de esta forma combinar los dos programas, haciendo que Excel extraiga información de IMS y la pegue en tablas. Sé que es posible hacerlo porque he heredado varios archivos que contienen macros que hacen este trabajo, el problema es que tienen contraseña y no puedo ver el código para intentar reproducirlo. Lo más lejos que llegue fue a abrir el archivo .mac de la macro de IMS e intentar copiarlo en VBS de Excel, pero a pesar de que el lenguaje es el mismo, siempre me da varios errores, alguien me podría explicar como puedo hacer esto? Muchas gracias a todos de antemano

Comment: `siempre me da varios errores` y cuáles son esos errores? Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y leas [ask] y [example] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida

Comment: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores.